# Using $wpdb | checking entered email against existing emails in db

Tags: database, forms, wpdb, validation

Without ranting too much, here is my snippet:

```
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
} else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);

    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
    } else {
        $emailTest = 'SELECT * FROM wp_email_subscribers WHERE email = '.$email;
        var_dump($email);
        var_dump($emailTest);
        $duplicateEmail = $wpdb->get_results($emailTest, OBJECT) or die(mysql_error());

        if (mysql_num_rows($duplicateEmail)!=0) {
            $emailErr = "Email address taken";
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me check the database for the entered email address and return an error if the email is already in the database?

Thanks, Jason.

Comment: You  can use wordpress default function for check email in users table like `if ( email_exists( $email ) ) {}`

Comment: souunds very helpful, how can i chose which database to search?

Comment: You can't. It's only for checking if an email exists in the WordPress users table. It's not a good suggestion.

Comment: Okay - back to my original question then c:

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `mysql_num_rows()` or `mysql_error()` when dealing with `$wpdb`. Even if you weren't, `mysql_error()` is for database errors, and an empty result set is not a database error.

If you want to know if results were returned, simply check the `count()` of the results:

```
$duplicateEmail = $wpdb->get_results($emailTest, OBJECT);

if ( count( $duplicateEmail ) > 0 ) {
    // Email already exits.
}
```

In terms of 'returning an error', that depends entirely on the context. If you just want a blank screen with an error message, then you could just use `wp_die()`:

```
$duplicateEmail = $wpdb->get_results($emailTest, OBJECT);

if ( count( $duplicateEmail ) > 0 ) {
    wp_die( 'Email already exits.' );
}
```

Or if this is an AJAX request you could use `wp_send_json_error()` to return a `400` error code with a message in JSON:

```
$duplicateEmail = $wpdb->get_results($emailTest, OBJECT);

if ( count( $duplicateEmail ) > 0 ) {
    wp_send_json_error( 'Email already exits.', 400 );
}
```

Also, you really should not put variables directly into SQL unescaped like you are. This leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Instead use `$wpdb->prepare()` to generate the query including your variable. You should also use `$wpdb->prefix` so that the query works even if the user is using a database prefix other than `wp_`:

```
$query   = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}email_subscribers WHERE email = %s", $email );
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );

if ( count( $results ) > 0 ) {
    wp_send_json_error( 'Email already exits.', 400 );
}
```

Comment: Such a helpful answer, well written code with a good overview, on top of that you have helped improve its security. Legend!